# Changing button color on click JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

**JavaScript:**

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("togglebtn"),
    i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
   acc[i].onclick = function () {
       this.classList.toggle("active");                               
   }
}
```

**html:**

```
<md-button class="md-fab togglebtn"></md-button>
```

**css:**

```
button.togglebtn:after {
   background-color: white;
   width: auto;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin-left: 5px;
   border: none;
   content:'';
}

button.togglebtn.active:after {
   width: auto;
   background-color: green;
   content:'close';
   font-size: 10px;
}
```

I am only able to change the color of the text but not the background color. I am trying to change the color when someone click on button. The :after is working in css but changing color is not working. Can someone suggest me, what I am doing wrong please

Comment: As you are using AngularJS, it may be better to do it *the Angular way*. See [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45959517/4927984).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just a CSS problem ,you are trying to set style of `after` but you need to set style of button and after separately:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("togglebtn"),
  i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
  }
}
```

```css
button.togglebtn:after {
  content: '';
}

button.togglebtn.active:after {
  content: 'close';
}

button.togglebtn {
  background-color: white;
  width: auto;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: none;
}

button.togglebtn.active {
  width: auto;
  background-color: green;
  content: ' close';
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button class="md-fab togglebtn">hello</button>
```

Comment: thats what i am doing but I am not able to change the color though

Comment: No,In addition  I've added css for `button.togglebtn` and `button.togglebtn.active`

Answer (score 3):

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("togglebtn");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
  }
}
```

```css
button.togglebtn.active {
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<button class="md-fab togglebtn">hello</button>
```

Comment: this is working fine but my button  changing the width

Comment: Give some fixed width.. It'll fix your problem, Remove width: auto on active

Answer (score 1):

As you are using AngularJS, I would suggest you to use [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) instead of plain JavaScript:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

```css
.active { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
    <button ng-class="{active: isActive}" ng-click="isActive =! isActive">Hello</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to create ng-class and set it up on ng click but its not functioning correctly. I also have another function on ng-click

Answer (score 0):

```
     .md-button.md-fab {
      line-height: 1% !important;
      min-width: 0;
      border-radius: 50%;
      position: fixed;
      margin-left: 400px;
      background-color: green;
      margin-top: -7px;
      }
      button.togglebtn:after {
        color: white;
        width: auto;
        margin-left: 5px;
        border: none;
        content:'open';
        font-size: 10px;

    }

button.togglebtn.active:after {
    width: auto;
    color: black;
    content:'close';
    font-size: 10px;
}

.md-button.md-fab {
    background-color: black !important;
}
.md-button.md-fab.active{
    background-color: yellow !important;
    content: 'yellow';
    color: white;
}
```